# Racket/Scheme - checking to see if a list is a sublist of another list

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, racket, sublist

I'm new to coding in racket, but I wanted to define a procedure that checks to see if a given list is a sublist (or part of) another list.

This is my code so far:

```
(define prefix?
  (lambda (lst1 lst2)
    (cond 
      ((equal? lst1 lst2) #t)
      ((null? lst2) #f)
      (else (prefix? lst1 (reverse (rest (reverse lst2))))))))

(define sublist?
  (lambda (lst1 lst2)
    (cond
      ((prefix? lst1 lst2) #t)
      ((null? lst2) #f)
      (else (prefix? lst1 (rest lst2))))))
```

I've tried most cases and it works the way it's supposed to but when I tried this test case:

```
(sublist? '(a b d) '(a b c a b d e))
```

It returns #f when it's supposed to return #t
I tried tracing the sublist? procedure but it isn't returning me any useful information.

Is there a logic error in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a logic error. The default case of `sublist?` should call `sublist?`, but instead calls `prefix?` so your `prefix?` will only be true if the match is either in index 0 or 1.

Also you have created a rather complex `prefix?`. Instead of comparing one by one element until any of them are empty you do a O(n) removal of the last element until you have a empty list before returning `#f` even if the two first elements are different. I would have compared the first elements and then recurred with `rest` in both args until either list is empty. Which one depends on the result and eg. `(prefix '(a b) '(w a d f s))` will stop computing after the very first check between `a` and `w`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(define sub?
  (lambda (l sub)
    (define test (lambda (x) (equal? x sub)))
    ((lambda (s) (s s l test))
     (lambda (s l k)
       (or (k '())
           (and (pair? l)
                (s s (cdr l)
                   (lambda (r)
                     (or (test r)
                         (k (cons (car l) r)))))))))))


(sub? '(a b c a b d e) '(b d e) )
(sub? '(a b c a b d e) '(c a b) )
(sub? '(a b c a b d e) '(a b c) )
(sub? '(a b c a b x e) '(a b d) )
```